# How to Publish a pub/sub message from a Cloud Function triggered by Cloud Pub/Sub

Tags: google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-pubsub

hope you're all safe! I need some help with my cloud function triggered by `Cloud Pub/Sub`...

I have a cloud function that is triggered by one of my topics. From this message I want to send a new message to another topic, but I'm getting some errors.

My Function:

```js
const { PubSub } = require("@google-cloud/pubsub");

exports.helloPubSub = async (message, context) => {
  try {
    let messageData = Buffer.from(message.data, "base64").toString();
    let messageObjectData = JSON.parse(messageData);

    //send pub/sub message to another topic
    sendPubSubMessage(messageObjectData);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error.message);
  }
};

function sendPubSubMessage(
  messageObjectData,
  topicName = "projects/myproject/topics/mytopic",
  data = JSON.stringify(messageObjectData)
) {
  const pubSubClient = new PubSub();

  async function publishMessage() {
    const dataBuffer = Buffer.from(data);

    try {
      const messageId = await pubSubClient.topic(topicName).publish(dataBuffer);
      console.log(`Message ${messageId} published.`);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(`Received error while publishing: ${error.message}`);
      process.exitCode = 1;
    }
  }

  publishMessage();
}
```

Package.json:

```
{
  "name": "sample-pubsub",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "dependencies": {
    "@google-cloud/pubsub": "^0.18.0"
  }
}
```

When this function runs I get this error:
`ERROR: PubSub is not a constructor`

I tried to change the dependency version to the last `2.18.3`, but then it does not deploy...

I also tried to load both versions:

```
{
  "name": "sample-pubsub",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "dependencies": {
    "@google-cloud/pubsub": "^0.18.0",
    "lastPubSub" : "npm:google-cloud/pubsub@^2.18.3",
  }
}
```

and got the same error...

Does anyone have any clue on how to fix it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You clearly have a dependency confusion. I don't know how to solve that in NodeJS, especially because when you use a newest one, you aren't able to deploy because you override the required library for the built in message receiver. If no NodeJS expert can answer you, the solution is to use an HTTP function and a PubSub push subscription to invoke your function.

Comment: Hey @guillaumeblaquiere, thank you for your comment! Do you think I would have the same problem using any other language? Merci!

Comment: It's possible, yes. I don't known which ones, but if the dependency used to received the message aren't in the same version as this one to publish messages, you have conflict and mess in the dependencies.

Comment: Juuuuust to try something... try `new PubSub({<project_id>});`. I'm not 100% sure there's a default constructor for the PubSub object in node (I'm a Python guy personally).

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for the comments, finally I got it...

**Solution:**

`package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "sample-pubsub",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "dependencies": {
    "@google-cloud/pubsub": "^0.18.0",
    "googlePub": "npm:@google-cloud/pubsub@^2.18.3"
  }
}
```